# Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, styled-components

Im getting this error trying to pass the value of a Map into a theme prop dynamically. what i do wrong?

ps: can't add "!" cause of eslint

```
interface ColorsInterface {
  bgColor: keyof ThemeVars['colors'];
  textColor: keyof ThemeVars['colors'];
}

const colorMap = new Map<string, ColorsInterface>([
  ['standard', { bgColor: 'primaryNormal', textColor: 'white' }],
  ['accent', { bgColor: 'accentNormal', textColor: 'white' }],
  ['neutral', { bgColor: 'grayExtraDark', textColor: 'white' }],
  ['flat', { bgColor: 'white', textColor: 'primaryNormal' }],
  ['text', { bgColor: 'white', textColor: 'grayExtraDark' }],
  ['disabled', { bgColor: 'grayLight', textColor: 'grayDark' }],
]);

export const ButtonWrapper = styled.button<ButtonInterface>`
${props =>
    props.buttonType &&
    css`
      background-color: ${props.theme.colors[colorMap.get(props.buttonType).bgColor]};
      color: ${colorMap.get(props.buttonType)?.textColor};
    `}  
`;
```

I get the error while passing the color to the theme in the background-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot force Map to have non-undefined return type. So you need to replace it with a simple object and assign a `Record` type to it.

Also I would recommend you to create a type union `ColorMapKeys` where you should define all possible keys.

```
type ColorMapKeys = 'standard' | 'accent' | 'neutral' | 'flat' | 'text' | 'disabled';

type ColorMap = Record<ColorMapKeys, ColorsInterface>;

const colorMap: ColorMap = {
  'standard': { bgColor: 'primaryNormal', textColor: 'white' },
  'accent': { bgColor: 'accentNormal', textColor: 'white' },
  'neutral': { bgColor: 'grayExtraDark', textColor: 'white' },
  'flat': { bgColor: 'white', textColor: 'primaryNormal' },
  'text': { bgColor: 'white', textColor: 'grayExtraDark' },
  'disabled': { bgColor: 'grayLight', textColor: 'grayDark' },
};

export const ButtonWrapper = styled.button<ButtonInterface>`
${(props: Props) =>
    props.buttonType &&
    css`
      background-color: ${props.theme.colors[colorMap[props.buttonType].bgColor]};
      color: ${colorMap[props.buttonType].textColor};
    `}  
`;
```

Now everything will work fine

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation but it doesn't solve the error

Comment: Sorry for the confusing answer. I have updated it. Let me know if the answer doesn't solve your problem or approve it if it does.